# How to send ether to a contract when deploying the contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

I have a contract like the following:

```
contract HoneyPot {

  mapping (address => uint) public balances;

  function HoneyPot() payable {
    balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;
  }

}
```

When deploying the contract I want to send some ether so the `balances[msg.sender]` for the account deploying the contract gets a balance equal to the amount of ether sent. How should this be done?

Here is how I am deploying the contract:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require('solc');
let Web3 = require('web3');
let web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
let go = fs.readFileSync('HoneyPot.sol').toString();
let compiledContract = solc.compile(go);
abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compiledContract.contracts[':HoneyPot'].interface);
contract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition);
byteCode = '0x'+compiledContract.contracts[':HoneyPot'].bytecode;
let gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: byteCode});
```

And finally the line that deploys it (without sending ether):

```
deployedContract = contract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0],data:byteCode,gas: gasEstimate+40000});
```

Comment: You can use the constructor for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `HoneyPot` function as follows:

```
deployedContract.HoneyPot({from:web3.eth.accounts[0],value:100})
```

Hope it helps~

Answer (score 1):

Just add "value" to the line that deploys the contract.

```
deployedContract = contract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], value: 5 wei, data:byteCode,gas: gasEstimate+40000});
```